# How to use PhoneGap/Cordova plugin in old IDEA 12?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, intellij-idea, phonegap-plugins

I have old version IntelliJ IDEA IDE - 12.1 and I have no reasons to update it.
I try to download a different version of this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7436?pr=  and install into an existing version of IDEA but always fails. 
Any advice, please.

Answer (score 1):

The new versions of the plugin require new versions of IntelliJ IDEA. They rely on new APIs added in the new versions and cannot work in IDEA 12.